# What is the : operator in ECMAScript/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

So an object like

```
{bar: 2}
```

will return the object itself, which is

```
{bar: 2}
```

But if I try

```
foo: {bar: 2}
```

Then I will get `2` instead

What is the : operator does here exactly? I can't find it in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators...

Comment: You're creating a labeled statement. And it's not an "operator".

Comment: @Pointy a labeled statement? But what does a labeled statement return a different result?

Comment: You're confusing the behavior of the `console` API with what the language actually does. Statements don't "return results" at all.

Comment: @Pointy - In specification terms, they actually do, which is part of why consoles show them. We just can't *access* their result values.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes that's true, though I've never really understood the point of that dark corner of the language spec. One of many.

Comment: @Pointy - Yeah. Though it may get exposed by [`do` expressions](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-do-expressions) someday...

Comment: wow that would be ... interesting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, absent other context:

```
{bar: 2}
```

does not create an object. It's a block statement with a single statement inside, and that statement has a label:

```
{
  bar: // the label
  2    // the expression statement
}
```

The text `{bar: 2}` is only an object when it appears in the context of an *expression*, like this:

```
foo({bar: 2}); // a function call to "foo", passing an object
```

Otherwise, a statement that begins with `{` is always interpreted as a block.

The statement

```
foo: {bar: 2}
```

is basically the same. Here, there's a label (`foo:`) outside the block, and a label (`bar:`) inside.

When you're trying code via a browser console, or Node, things get weird because the console itself has behavior intended to help with debugging but which is also *different* from language semantics in some cases. JavaScript is not directly a "REPL-friendly" syntax, so the console mechanism has to be clever.

Answer (score 5):

JavaScript doesn't have a `:` operator. But `:` is used in various syntax productions.

*Within* an object initializer's property initializer, the `:` separates the property *name* from the property *value*. That's what you're using in your first example.

At statement level, not in an object initializer, a name followed by `:` is a [*statement label*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label). That's what your `foo: {bar: 2}` example is. Labels are mostly used for directed `break` and `continue`.

(`:` is also used in the [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), `condition ? a :b`.)

So then the question is: Why do you see `{bar: 2}` in the console in the first example, and `2` in the console in the second example?

The answer is that it's special behavior of the console, in two different ways:

1. When you type `{bar: 2}` into the console, it treats that as an expression, and so it sees it as an object initializer and creates, then logs, the object. But if you had `{bar: 2}` at the top level of script code, it wouldn't be an expression, it would be a block with a labelled statement in it. Treating it as an expression is console-specific.
2. When you type `foo: {bar: 2}` into the console, it correctly identifies that a labelled statement — two of them, in fact: `foo: ...` and `bar: 2`. The `{}` are a block, not an object initializer, and so the inner `bar:` is a label.

   So why `2` then? Because it's showing you the result of that code, which isn't available to us syntactically, but is defined by the specification. The result of a block is the last value evaluated within that block, and the labels are transparent. The last value in the `{bar: 2}` block is `2`, so the block's value is `2`, so that's what it shows. But again, this is not something we can directly observe in code, it's console behavior.